# AVG mysql php error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resourc

Tags: php, mysql, average

I'm tryig to get the avg from column "valor_premio", but I have this error:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/u566181585/public_html/index.php on line 61 Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/u566181585/public_html/index.php on line 63
```

And the first echo returns that:`Resource id #13`

```
$sel2 = mysql_query( "SELECT AVG(valor_premio) as avg_valor FROM novaaaa WHERE categoria='Identidade'")  or (mysql_error());
echo $sel2;
$media_ident2=mysql_query($sel2);
echo $media_ident2;
$media_ident = mysql_fetch_array($media_ident2);
echo $media_ident;
```

What is wrong? How can I get the avg?

Comment: You're using `mysql_query` twice; remove one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$media_ident2=mysql_query($sel2);
                          ^^^^^
```

`$sel2` is the RESULT HANDLE of your previous `mysql_query()` call. You cannot use a result handle like that. You MUST provide a STRING containing your sql as the parameter.

What you want is

```
$sql = "SELECT ..."; // note: **NO** mysql_query() call...

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: thanks @Marc B

I don't have the error anymore, but I'm getting from $media_ident the return: Array. How I should get the number?